# Подключение Logs API к ClickHouse

Tags: python, clickhouse

База установлена на удаленном сервере. Для интеграции использую python скрипт из документации https://tech.yandex.ru/metrika/doc/api2/logs/fields/clickhouse-integration-docpage/

ВЫполняем команду:

```
py -2 metrica_logs_api.py -mode history -source visits
```

Получаю ответ с ошибкой:

```
    2018-07-27 20:01:12 MainProcess INFO     UserRequest(token=u'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', counter_id=u'xxxxxx', start_date_str=u'2018-03-19', end_date_str='2018-07-25', source='visits', fields=(u'ym:s:counterID', u'ym:s:dateTime', u'ym:s:date', u'ym:s:clientID'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "metrica_logs_api.py", line 122, in <module>
    user_request.source):
  File "C:\Users\death\logs_api_integration\clickhouse.py", line 159, in is_data_present
    if not is_db_present():
  File "C:\Users\death\logs_api_integration\clickhouse.py", line 83, in is_db_present
    return CH_DATABASE in get_dbs()
  File "C:\Users\death\logs_api_integration\clickhouse.py", line 73, in get_dbs
    return get_clickhouse_data('SHOW DATABASES')\
  File "C:\Users\death\logs_api_integration\clickhouse.py", line 27, in get_clickhouse_data
    r = requests.post(host, data=query, auth=(CH_USER, CH_PASSWORD))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 112, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 58, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 512, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 622, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 495, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', BadStatusLine('SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4p1 Debian-10+deb9u3\n',))
```

Не конектица... Кто нибудь сталкивался с подобным? Куда копнуть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выглядит как некорректно указанная пара хост/порт для ClickHouse в config.json — вместо ClickHouse там ответил sshd

Comment: Да, всё верно, в конфиге был порт неверно указан :( Спасибо!